# Can all Android applications load a FLEX component if I provide one through my SDK I'm developing?

Tags: android, apache-flex, sdk

I'm writing an SDK that I want to claim any Android application can use to load my component from the SDK for use in display in their Android application.

If I write this component in FLEX would any Android application be able to load this FLEX component or would some software development companies require something else because they cannot load a FLEX component in their current Android application development environment?

I want to know if I only need to write one FLEX component or several different components to support different development environments.

Comment: Well, a Flex component obviously would not be able to be used in a native Java application. Beyond that, I really am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Yarg, so if they use Java to make their app they couldn't load a FLEX component? This means I will most likely have to create the SDK to support both Java apps and FLEX apps. Twice the work!

Comment: Flex and Java do not mix. Flex is an SDK for ActionScript 3, which uses Adobe AIR to run on desktop and mobile platforms. There is no way to use Flex in Java.